# Can't setup craft cms on mac

Tags: php, bash, xampp, craftcms

I downloaded a craft project on my htdocs folder from xampp on my mac. When I run `./craft setup` on the terminal it shows me this error:

```
-bash: ./craft: Permission denied
```

How to fix this error?
Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try `sudo ./craft setup`!

The error means that the script does something that the user is not privileged to do!

If that does not help, try to set other user rights to the file!
Please try `chmod u+x craft` and then `./craft setup`!

Comment: thank's but when I enter to this URL `http://localhost/test_craft/web/index.php?p=admin/install` it shows me this error:`HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Template not found: dashboard`

Comment: This is another Problem, maybe open a new question?